Open reference from Zotero using rofi / dmenu
I have a number of collections in Zotero (a bibliography manager). I would like to be able to open the associated PDFs using rofi or dmenu, and have a list of entries to choose from of the following form:
[COLLECTION][AUTHORS]TITLE.pdf

Has anyone created a script for this?

just to be sure I understand correctly, you want to write a program/script that interacts with zotero's database, gets all publications from there, get all PDFs from these, and then shows you a list of them using dmenu/rofi, right? Or something else?

yes, but without the "get the PDFs part", as these are already attached in Zotero (or rather, I'd like a list only of those publications which have a PDF attached)

but you don't want this to happen from the zotero UI, but externally?

Yes, that is right!

So, first instinct was to use zotero as software, and call into it to get the info you want; after all, it already knows how to structure the data from its database! It also already has HTTP "REST"-alike endpoints that are used by the browser plugins to tell zotero to save a page etc.
Sadly, these endpoints don't currently support getting the kind of information you want. I'd say, though, that the architecturally sensible approach here is to follow the guide on that server's extendability, and writing a zotero extension, that just contains the bare minimum javascript to do the query you need, when being asked via HTTP, and returns JSON (so to not be overly-specific to say dmenu and of no use for anyone else nor you tomorrow). Then, you just use a HTTP client library or command line program to get that data, and a JSON parser library or command line program to convert the JSON into line-separated entries for dmenu. In the case of a shell script, the programs to do that would be curl and jq.
The alternative is reading the sqlite database yourself. Sure, that can be done, but has the distinctive downside of breaking every time anything changes in the database layout, which, being an internal format, can happen without warning. sqlite3 is the sqlite command line client, and you should be able to write a SELECT statement (probably with enough JOINs, combined with copious amounts of SQLite's string-generating format function) to make my head dizzy) that selects all PDF information, combines them with author and title information, and outputs resulting strings. SQLite is indeed rather powerful! If you can't get SQLite to produce the output dmenu needs itself, then you'd set sqlite3's output mode to JSON (.mode json) before running your SELECT statement and do the post-processing in jq.
(or of course, here's me advocating for not using shell scripts for complex data processing operations, but a "proper" language of your choice; e.g. Python would make all – querying REST-alike endpoints via HTTP, parsing JSON, generating specifically formatted string output and reading SQLite databases – just very-few-lines-of-code functions that can rely on built-in libraries.)
